# Ubuntu 12.04 KVM running Ubuntu 12.04 with linux-image-virtual crash on boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

One of my VMs is stuck on "pause" in virsh. If I destroy and restart it, it will go to pause after a bit of time as "running".
I can at best enter my username at login if I'm quick but it'll then shutdown.

I don't know where to start with this so any help would be great!!

I can access the VMs files via guestfish.
the kern.log and syslog don't populate new lines. This is the last input I get from kern.log:

```
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 3.2.0-34-virtual (buildd@allspice) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) ) #53-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 15 11:08:40 UTC 2012 (Ubuntu 3.2.0-34.53-virtual 3.2.33)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: root=UUID=61d48b48-a06a-48fb-842e-b38014086a93 ro quiet splash
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 (reserved)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000000100000 - 00000000dfffc000 (usable)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000dfffc000 - 00000000e0000000 (reserved)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000feffc000 - 00000000ff000000 (reserved)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 00000000fffc0000 - 0000000100000000 (reserved)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000]  BIOS-e820: 0000000100000000 - 0000000a20000000 (usable)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] DMI 2.4 present.
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: Bochs Bochs, BIOS Bochs 01/01/2007
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] e820 update range: 0000000000000000 - 0000000000010000 (usable) ==> (reserved)
Dec 13 11:21:08 soft201 kernel: [    0.000000] e820 remove range: 00000000000a0000 - 0000000000100000 (usable)
Dec 13
```

As you can see the last line gets cut off.
I don't even know if this is that relevant. dmesg logs are empty.

The qemu log for the VM returns this:

```
2012-12-13 12:29:47.584+0000: starting up
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-1.0 -enable-kvm -m 40960 -smp 14,sockets=14,cores=1,threads=1 -name numerink201 -uuid f4a889ed-a089-05d0-cc9d-9825ab1faeba -nodefconfig -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=charmonitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/numerink201.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control -rtc base=utc -no-shutdown -drive file=/var/lib/libvirt/images/client.soft.fr/tmpcZAD9U.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,format=qcow2 -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0,bootindex=1 -fsdev local,security_model=none,id=fsdev-fs0,path=/home/shared_folders/soft201 -device virtio-9p-pci,id=fs0,fsdev=fsdev-fs0,mount_tag=hostshare,bus=pci.0,addr=0x5 -netdev tap,fd=18,id=hostnet0 -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=02:00:00:1d:b9:e7,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 -chardev pty,id=charserial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=charserial0,id=serial0 -usb -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -vga cirrus -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x4
char device redirected to /dev/pts/3
qemu: terminating on signal 15 from pid 28248
2012-12-13 12:30:14.455+0000: shutting down
```

I've added more logging, libvirt.log gives me this:

```
2012-12-13 13:24:38.525+0000: 27694: info : libvirt version: 0.9.8
2012-12-13 13:24:38.525+0000: 27694: error : virExecWithHook:328 : Cannot find 'pm-is-supported' in path: No such file or directory
2012-12-13 13:24:38.525+0000: 27694: warning : qemuCapsInit:856 : Failed to get host power management capabilities
2012-12-13 13:24:39.865+0000: 27694: error : virExecWithHook:328 : Cannot find 'pm-is-supported' in path: No such file or directory
2012-12-13 13:24:39.865+0000: 27694: warning : lxcCapsInit:77 : Failed to get host power management capabilities
2012-12-13 13:24:39.866+0000: 27694: error : virExecWithHook:328 : Cannot find 'pm-is-supported' in path: No such file or directory
2012-12-13 13:24:39.866+0000: 27694: warning : umlCapsInit:87 : Failed to get host power management capabilities
```

I don't really know where to go from here.

I'll post whatever info you require

Comment: Find out more about `qemu: terminating on signal 15 from pid 28248`. What is/was this pid? (`ps aux | grep 28248`)

Comment: it was libvirt. I've since then fixed the issue and will post full answer later in the day when I get time. Thanks for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've resolved this.

The simple answer to this was that the host ran out of disk space as the guest image file was getting larger. Libvirt would then shutdown the guest everytime it tried to write to the disk (which was always in my case).

Thus adding more disk space or moving the image to a larger disk/mount solved my problem in the short run.

For the sake of helping other people with similar issues. There is a bug where the [qcow2 image increases it's size above the virtual limit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qemu-kvm/+bug/1025244). So if this happens to you don't just assume your host has enough disk space because you limited your image in size!!